# Using chef/artifactory-client as chef remote_file provider

Tags: chef-infra, artifactory, chef-recipe

Chef [developed a Ruby gem for interacting with Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/blog/infrastructure-as-binaries-with-chef-and-artifactory-five-best-practices/) that Chef cookbooks could use to download artifacts and perform other actions.  I assumed it would be leveraged as a provider for resources like [remote_file](https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_file.html), however there is no example code provided, documentation on using it explicitly in Chef, or others who have taken this approach.

1. How have you integrated Chef with Artifactory?
2. Are your cookbooks/recipes redistributable without tight coupling to Artifactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifactory is a universal binary hosting software, and even if you don't need its various specific API compatible options (RubyGems /PyPi /Docker /etc), you can still create a "dumb" file repository that acts like a web server that can serve files anonymously or via authenticated methods.

It is also an excellent caching proxy, I often use it in front of other "dumb" file repositories like the NodeJS.org download directory for the NodeJS binary archives or other remote installers that I want to make sure I have a backup copy of any version I've used in our pipeline.

To use it for "remote_file" you can simply create a new repository called 'local-config-artifacts' and upload your files there. The really nice thing about Artifactory is it can perform the metadata calculations for you (md5/sha1/sha256/etc) and then you can enter that value in your cookbook recipe so that you can have an "idempotent" download that will only re-download if the checksum changes.

Comment: Yeah I think the artifactory gem is really mean for Ruby development rather than Chef cookbooks to leverage.  Going on that assumption, I agree setting up Artifactory as a file server is probably the best bet.  Thanks!

Comment: For internal company cookbooks using the gem is probably handy for being able to more easily grab artifacts especially when you have authentication turned on, The #5 snippet from the post you linked explains it well, `Chef has created the Artifactory RubyGem that authenticates you and makes REST API calls to Artifactory from your Cookbook.`

Answer (score 1):

The two projects (the Artifactory gem and Chef) are not related and the former is not a cookbook. There is a a cookbook called `artifact` with a custom resource for downloading from Artifactory but I'm not sure it is maintained anymore.

Comment: Thanks for mention of artifact cookbook though I agree it looks disused and not ideal.

Comment: Yep, I suspect you're on your own and will need to write something yourself.

Comment: Ideally there should be a way for Chef cookbooks to leverage Artifactory in such a way that the cookbooks can be redistributed on the Chef Supermarket without being tightly coupled to Artifactory.

Comment: That would be nice, but it does not really exist at this time. My poise-archive cookbook is built to be plugable though, so you might be able to use that in certain cases.

Comment: You can use the built in remote_file resource for simple tasks or the Ark cookbook: https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/ark

Answer (score 0):

There is a wiki page on how to configure Chef repositories in Artifactory and how to configure your knife to install from Artifactory:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Chef+Cookbook+Repositories

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks but that's not the issue in question.  I'm talking about Chef cookbook recipes being able to retrieve files from Artifactory but in a way that allows you to continue using things like remote_file resource.